# Strange Delegate Reference Behaviour

Tags: c#, delegates, reference, ienumerable, stack-overflow

I have a need to pass the results of a source function (which returns an `IEnumerable`) through a list of other processing functions (that each take and return an `IEnumerable`).

All is fine up to that point, but I also need to allow the processing functions to perform multiple loops over their input enumerables.

So rather than pass in `IEnumerable<T>`, I thought I would change the input parameter to `Func<IEnumerable<T>>` and allow each of the functions to restart the enumerable if required.

Unfortunately, I'm now getting a stack overflow where the final processing function is calling itself rather than passing the request back down the chain.

The example code is a bit contrived but hopefully gives you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func<IEnumerable<String>> getResults = () => GetInputValues("A", 5);

        List<String> valuesToAppend = new List<String>();

        valuesToAppend.Add("B");
        valuesToAppend.Add("C");

        foreach (var item in valuesToAppend)
        {
             getResults = () => ProcessValues(() => getResults(),item);
        }

        foreach (var item in getResults())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

    }

    public static IEnumerable<String> GetInputValues(String value, Int32 numValues)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numValues; i++)
        {
            yield return value;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<String> ProcessValues(Func<IEnumerable<String>> getInputValues, String appendValue)
    {
        foreach (var item in getInputValues())
        {
            yield return item + " " + appendValue;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getResults` is captured as a *variable*, not a value. I don't really like the overall approach you're using here (it seems convoluted), but you should be able to fix the stackoverflow by changing the capture:

```
    foreach (var item in valuesToAppend)
    {
         var tmp1 = getResults;
         var tmp2 = item;
         getResults = () => ProcessValues(() => tmp1(),tmp2);
    }
```

On a side note: `IEnumerable[<T>]` is already *kinda* repeatable, you simply call `foreach` another time - is is `IEnumerator[<T>]` that (despite the `Reset()`) isn't - but also, I think it is worth doing trying to do this *without* needing to ever repeat the enumeration, since *in the general case* that simply cannot be guaranteed to work.

---

Here's a simpler (IMO) implementation with the same result:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        IEnumerable<String> getResults = Enumerable.Repeat("A", 5);
        List<String> valuesToAppend = new List<String> { "B", "C" };
        foreach (var item in valuesToAppend) {
            string tmp = item;
            getResults = getResults.Select(s => s + " " + tmp);
        }
        foreach (var item in getResults) {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first example avoids the stackoverflow but now returns: ACC, ACC etc.

Comment: Thanks. Now working! The real world processing code needs to work on a large number of items in memory and the multiple passes are therefore required to allow it to work in low memory situations. I hadn't realised that IEnumerable was clever enough to be repeatable on its own - is there any reason I shouldn't rely on that behaviour?

Comment: @rob - yes; it depends **entirely** on the underlying implementation of the enumerator. For example, I might write an enumerator that pulls data from an open socket - can't repeat that. Or if I am evil I could write an enumerator that pulls data from a `Random` instance, or `Guid` - if you can make those repeat you're doing well.

Comment: @rob - and those problems affect your function based code **in exactly the same way**. So you've added a layer of complexity but not solved the problem.

Comment: The source will always be a disk read (where the position is reset inside the method) so I'm happy to go with the simpler option and ditch the delegates. Thanks for your help Marc.